# whats wrong with this?

Tags: energy

a car weighs 100kg and has Velocity 0. it accelerates and its speed become 10m/s.
its kinetic energy would be 100*10*10/2=5000j.

from another view car is at rest and the world accelerates and has now 10m/s speed.

as energy must be constant it should be:5000=10*10/2*(world mass except car)
world mass except car=100kg?

am i using conservation of energy in wrong way, or i cant have that point of view?

Answer (score 1):

The kinetic energy you determine objects to have depends on what reference frame you're in. Therefore, there's no problem here.

Comment: so it means i cant change my point of view and expect the same 5000j?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Energy is dependent on the coordinate frame, so in one frame the car has $E=5000J$ and in another it has $E=0$, nothing wrong about it! This is because energy is not a scalar but a component of a vector, the momentum 4-vector

$$p^\mu=(E, \vec p)$$

It transforms with a Lorentz matrix, like the coordinate 4-vector.

Comment: so it means i cant change my point of view and expect the same 5000j?

Comment: Exactly! For some quantities you can, those are called scalars. But for energy you cannot, since energy is not a scalar but a component of a vector.